# How to access Eclipse refactoring scripts from command line for automation

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

Eclipse allows to create refactoring scripts through the GUI. I'm looking for a way to generate the script files with inputs from an external module and then automate the refactoring based on them. Would it be possible to do this by a mere jar/class call in a command line (bash script)?

Are there other options to do automated find and replace on large code base which won't break the code? Typically the projects contain all sorts of files java,jsp,css,html,Make,....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Eclipse does not include such an application (look for all definitions of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point). It wouldn't be too hard to build one on top of the functionality of `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring` and `org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing ... just in case anybody is interested I found the following articles [Unleashing the Power of Refactoring] (http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html), [LTK]
(http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-LTK/ltk.html), [Eclipse Refactoring] (http://people.clarkson.edu/~dhou/courses/EE564-s07/Eclipse-Refactoring.pdf). All of them are quite old but that should not be a problem.